# Selecting selectbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a question about selecting selectboxes with Javascript. I have upload the files on http://www.mikevierwind.nl/javascript/risicoinventarisatie.htm Here you see a table with a lot of questions and radiobuttons. Every question have 2 radiobuttons, yes and no.

When you go to the first question. "Diabetes" Than you choose for the radiobutton "ja" You see that another question will now show. But when I choose for "nee" than the question must be gone. How can I create that with the Javascript? My Javascript code is:

```
 var diabetes = false;
 var diabetesvraag = $("#blokken table.lichamelijkegezondheid .diabetesextra")
 var buttondiabetes = $("#blokken table.lichamelijkegezondheid .diabetesja")

 diabetesvraag.hide();
 buttondiabetes.click(function()
 {   
  if(diabetes == false)
  {
   diabetes = true;
   diabetesvraag.show();
  }

  else
  {
   diabetes = false;
   diabetesvraag.hide();
  }
  return false;
 });
```

Comment: Are you sure? Answering "nee" will make the question invisible, but what if the user made a mistake and want to undo its answer? Also, I see that there is a little problem with selecting the items (you can only choose one "nee" and one "ja").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all you need to get your HTML corrected. Each set of "yes" and "no" radiobuttons need to be grouped together with the correct `name` attribute. This will tell the browser that only one of each set of "yes" and "no" is selectable. The `name` must be unique for each condition, however. Something like this should do:

```
<span class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="condition_selection" value="yes" id="yes" />
    <label for="yes">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="condition_selection" value="no" id="no" />
    <label for="no">No</label></span>
```

You should also use the `for` attribute for the `label` element for accessibility reasons, and try using something else other than tables for marking up this form, but that's not relevant to the question here.

---

Next, you can try simplifying the Javascript code using the `change` event handler to check for both states, with something like this:

```
$('.add_qns').hide();

$('.radio :radio').change(function(){
    if(this.value === 'yes'){
        $(this).parent().next('.add_qns').show();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().next('.add_qns').hide();
    }
});
```

You have the change the selector `$(this).parent().next('.add_qns')` to suit your markup. See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/BcAwH/ for a live demo.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I gone used this!

Comment: @robin At Stack Overflow, if an answer has solved your problem, you can mark the answer as accepted, by clicking on the green checkmark on the side of the answer. This gives both the asker and the answerer a reward for their effort, and marks the question as solved. Also, glad to be of service :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `class="diabetesja"` to the nee buttons as well, as your code only assigns the click event to the `.diabetesja` radio buttons..

Alternatively you could add a class `class="diabetesnee"` to your **nee** radio buttons and change the

```
var buttondiabetes = $("#blokken table.lichamelijkegezondheid .diabetesja")
```

to

```
var buttondiabetes = $("#blokken table.lichamelijkegezondheid .diabetesja, #blokken table.lichamelijkegezondheid .diabetesnee")
```

The point is that both radio buttons (Ja and Nee) need to have the click handler..